# Trying to pass data forward, but can't populate the next view controller's array

Tags: ios, objective-c

in **aViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface aViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *pageImages;
@end
```

in **bViewController.m**

```
#import "aViewController.h"

// ...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    aViewController *testViewController = [[aViewController alloc] init];
    [testViewController.pageImages addObject:@"lalala yeyeye"];

    NSLog(@"%@", testViewController.pageImages); // Error?

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:testViewController animated:YES];
}
```

The NSLog in **bViewController.m** outputs:

```
2013-10-08 18:23:38.398 quo.mk.e[56804:1ca03] (null)
```

What did I do wrong here? Why did the NSMutableArray remain empty although I had added an object into it?

Update: both UIViewController objects are made programmatically. I am using [the passing data forward tips mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/884836) to populate the array, but I'm stumped on why it won't work.

Comment: are u initialising ur array in aViewController.m viewDidLoad Method??

Comment: @iProgrammer as it is a `@property`, I thought iOS automatically initialized it.

Comment: You have to allocate the array I mean to say that..:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you allocate `aViewController` it won't allocate the objects inside that class.

You need to allocate them also, means you need to allocate memory for the `NSMutableArray` else it will be `nil`.

You should do like:

```
aViewController *testViewController = [[aViewController alloc] init];
testViewController.pageImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[testViewController.pageImages addObject:@"lalala yeyeye"];
NSLog(@"%@", testViewController.pageImages);
```

Comment: This works. Just wanted to add that I initially thought having `pageImages` as a `@property` means it gets initialized automatically. I guess not.

Comment: @hfz: no, it won't be initialized. You need to initialize each member object. Or you can override the `- (id)init` in the `aViewController` and allocate each member object there